# How do I get the current year with Perl?

Tags: perl

in a script, the variables are defined with "my".

I now have the variable

```
my $timestamp = time();
```

inserted and would now like to output the year.

With

```
my $timestamp = time();
my $year=$timestamp;
```

the timestamp is displayed correctly in the `print` section with `$year`.

How do I have to define `$year` so that the date, e.g. `date(Y)` is output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [localtime](http://p3rl.org/localtime) instead.

```perl
my @t = localtime;
print $t[5] + 1900;
```

Or reach for something more highlevel:

```perl
use Time::Piece;
my $time = localtime;
print $time->year;
```

See [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece) for details.

Comment: Or `my $year = ( localtime )[5] + 1900;`

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Perl the following should be easy to understand:

```
#  get the current time in seconds since the Unix epoch (January 1, 1970, at 00:00:00 UTC).
my $timestamp = time();

# get values representing the local time
my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst) = localtime($timestamp);

#$year represents the number of years since 1900, so we add 1900 to it to get the current year.
my $current_year = $year + 1900;

print "The current year is: $current_year\n";
```